# How to display the full list on scene in unity

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

1. i am a beginner in unity i have a list which consist of some names.
   I want to display all those names in the scene. i am able to log all
   the names in list in the console.i need to display them on the scene

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i <= Items.Count - 1; i++) 
   {
        b = (Items[i].ToString());
        DisplayListText.text = b;
   }
   ```
2. Items is my List
3. DisplayListText is the text i created on the canvas
4. when i run this code i am able to display only one name.
5. how to display all the names from the List to the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the text instead of adding to it.
Change this:

```
DisplayListText.text = b;
```

to this:

```
DisplayListText.text += b + '\n';
```

Comment: This is not what he is after.

Comment: @Everts What else?

Comment: Hmm, ok , I thought he was trying to get the scene names by code as I was saying in the comment. Well let's see what he is after coz that pb would be too trivial.

Comment: now it works but actulay ,overlap...every time the list and string is printed...ie if my list is [ hi, hallo,bye] first i add hi  then "hi" apears on the screen..then again i add hallo ..so the hi / hi hallo is printed for the final one hi/ hi hallo/ hi hallo bye ..this is the pattern ..i need to show always only one string soo duplication doesnot happen

Comment: @Martinj It is *very* hard to understand what you want to achieve here.